# How to generate recaptcha token in integration test in java?

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I am trying to write integration test (Junit) in java to test recaptcha v3. But I cannot hardcode recaptcha token.

I tried referring to https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do but couldn't find any way to generate recaptcha token for junit.

I also referred to - https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3 but it seems that only JavaScript API is available for token generation. I am looking for an API in Java to generate the recaptcha token.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.